# Excel: Optimizing a bunch of very heavy SUMIFS

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have some data that I want summed matching certain criteria

Example data:

```
  A    B   C   D
  Id   Id2 Id3 Val
  1    1   8   6
  1    2   7   7
  1    3   3   8
  1    4   6   4
  1    4   78  7
  1    1   2   9
  1    3   1   4
  1    4   3   6
  1    1   5   8
  1    4   7   2
```

Now I want the **Val** summed for every Id, based on certain criteria (e.g. Id2=4 and Id3=2) for every **Id** which has 100 values, but I want to avoid rerunning the sumifs for every **Id** since the table is heavy.

What I have been doing so far is to

```
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "=1", B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2")
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "=2", B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2")
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "=3", B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2")
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "=4", B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2") ...
```

(if I remember the syntax of sumifs correctly)

Is there a faster way that avoids rerunning the sumifs for each **Id** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to figure lots of `SUM`s in this way, it's best done with a [pivot table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx).

You may also try [`DSUM`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/dsum-HP005209069.aspx), but I doubt it's going to be any faster than SUMIF.

Comment: Thank you a bunch, I ended up using 3 pivot tables and they made the data processing 1000x faster :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also do an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) which should also be lightning fast.

So select the range that you want your results, then push `F2` to enter where you want your first formula. Then put in the below array formula:

```
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "="&{1;2;3;4}, B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2")
```

or

```
= SUMIFS(D:D, A:A, "="&G1:G4, B:B, "=4", C:C, "=2")
```

where `G1` to `G4` have your values you want to iterate over.

This will make it so it only grabs the data only once rather than multiple times and will return all the values one time rather than multiple times.

If you want to iterate from left to right use a `comma` instead of a `semicolon` in your array.

When you enter an array formula enter it this way:

```
Ctrl+Shift+Enter
```